# Images not loading when deployed to Vercel

Tags: reactjs, vercel

I am making a portfolio website and for each project, I have a few images and videos to display.
Folder structure like this:

[image]

and I have a map function to fetch and display all the images:

```
{
  project.Images.map((img)=>(
   <div key={img} onClick={()=>setSelectedImage(img,project.Name)}>
      <img src={getImgSrc(img,project.Name)} alt="" className={`w-[60px] h-[50px] mr-[10px] rounded-sm hover:cursor-pointer mb-[10px] ${displayingImg==img?('border-2 border-gray-400'):('')}`} />
    </div>
))
}
```

this is the `getImgSrc` function:

```
    const getImgSrc = (src:string,name:string)=>{
        const img = `../assets/projects/${name}/${src}.png`;
        return new URL(img, import.meta.url).href;
    }
```

The images get displayed perfectly when on local host.
However, when I reply my app to Vercel the images are not loaded. does any one know why?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const getImgSrc = (src:string,name:string)=>{
    const img = `../assets/projects/${name}/${src}.png`;
    return require(img);
}
```